# 301 redirect or channel-level tag in SoundCloud's RSS feed?

Tags: rss, itunes, soundcloud, podcast

How can I implement a 301 redirect on a SoundCloud RSS feed? Specifically, I'm looking at the podcast feed that needs the redirection away from SoundCloud.

If it is possible to place a 301, how permanent is it?

If SoundCloud isn't open enough to allow a 301 redirect, then how can I place a channel-level tag in the RSS feed?

The point of this is to thoroughly move a podcast away from SoundCloud's feed without losing a single subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure Soundcloud allows for 301 and I would be surprised if they allowed you to "mangle" with the feed's XML itself.

For regular, text based feeds it is possible to write *warning* entries such as "This feed won't be updated, please subscribe to XXX instead", but I doubt that podcast readers will show text entries to their users.

I think the only way for you would be to ask Soundcloud support if they allow 301s...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I knew beforehand, but wanted to ensure. SoundCloud doesn't currently allow this, so using their feed means someone is held hostage.